# Is there an method to stop the flow until I get response from API in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, api, post, grand-central-dispatch

Basically, we do have an APIHelper class where GET & POST methods are implemented, that can be called from any of the View Controllers, we will be sending an Access Token for security in the header, once that access token is expired we need to call an API for getting access token and need to send the updated token in the header.

```
class func postMethod(methodName: String, success: @escaping (AnyObject?, String?)->Void, Failure:@escaping (NSError)->Void)
{
    do {
        
        if ReachabilityManager.shared.isConnectedToNetwork() == false
        {
            PageNavigation.moveToInternet()
            
            
        } else {
            
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let urlPath = URL(string: "\(AppConstants.BaseUrl)" + "\(methodName)")
            var request = URLRequest(url: urlPath! as URL)
            
            print( "JSON request is \(urlPath!)")
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            
            request = WebAPIHelper.headers(methodType: "POST", methodName: methodName, request: request, isAddUserAuthorization: false)
            
            let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(CommonDBHelper.getActiveUserRefreshToken())
            request.httpBody = jsonBody
            
            let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
                if(error == nil)
                {
                    do
                    {
                        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
                        {
                            let headers = httpResponse.allHeaderFields
                            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                            
                             if (statusCode == 200)
                            {
                                let JSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                                
                                if let currentServerTime = headers["Date"] as? String
                                {
                                    success(JSON as AnyObject?, currentServerTime)
                                }
                                else{
                                    success(JSON as AnyObject?, nil)     // Closure being called as a function
                                }
                            }
                            
                            else
                            {
                                GenericMethods.showAlert(alertMessage: "Some error occured. Please try again later")
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            GenericMethods.showAlert(alertMessage: "Some error occured. Please try again later")
                        }
                    }
                    catch let JSONError as NSError
                    {
                        Failure(JSONError as NSError)
                        
                        print("JSON Error \(JSONError)")
                        GenericMethods.showAlert(alertMessage: "Some error occured. Please try again later")
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Failure(error! as NSError)
                    GenericMethods.showAlert(alertMessage: "Some error occured. Please try again later")
                }
            })
            task.resume()
        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error in catch \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
}
```

So GET & POST will be called by many threads at a time, So how to keep all the calls in Waiting mode till I get a response from Access Token API, Is there any solution for this type of Scenario?

```
class func headers(methodType:String, methodName:String, request:URLRequest, isAddUserAuthorization : Bool) -> URLRequest
{
    let methodName = methodName
    var request = request
    
    


        if isTokenExpired(){
            
            //how to keep waiting all other api calling in waiting mode here until i get response
            
            RefreshTokenAPI(completed: { (accesstoken) ->Void in
                request.addValue(accesstoken, forHTTPHeaderField: "AccessToken")
            })
            
        }
        else{
            request.addValue(getAccessTokenFromDefaults(), forHTTPHeaderField: "AccessToken")
        }
        
    
    
   
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    
    
    
    print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields!)
    
    return request as URLRequest
}
```

Comment: reading just the question, you can try 
Semaphore, DispatchGrooup or sync. i recommend you reading about them.

Comment: I hope you should have a look at the whole code!!! @MohmmadS

Comment: @Ganesh Why do you say that? Don’t just say “look at the whole code”, but rather tell Mohmmad to what you’re trying to draw his attention.

Comment: FWIW, I’d really suggest you _avoid_ semaphores, groups, and sync. You should follow asynchronous patterns, not try to make inherently asynchronous methods behave synchronously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal here is to initiate the subsequent request after you have received the access token. One would generally employ a completion handler pattern, e.g. a closure that is called only after the access request is retrieved:

```
class func headers(methodType: String, methodName: String, request: URLRequest, isAddUserAuthorization: Bool, completion: @escaping (URLRequest) -> Void) {
    var request = request

    // presumably you have code that is using methodType and methodName, too ...

    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

    if isTokenExpired() { 
        refreshTokenAPI { accesstoken in
            request.addValue(accesstoken, forHTTPHeaderField: "AccessToken")
            completion(request)
        }
    } else {
        request.addValue(getAccessTokenFromDefaults(), forHTTPHeaderField: "AccessToken")
        completion(request)
    }
}
```

Then rather than:

```
request = WebAPIHelper.headers(methodType: "POST", methodName: methodName, request: request, isAddUserAuthorization: false)

...

// currently issuing request here
```

The caller would move everything dependent upon the `request` in the `headers` completion handler:

```
WebAPIHelper.headers(methodType: "POST", methodName: methodName, request: request, isAddUserAuthorization: false) { request in
    // issue request here
    ...
}

// but not here
```

This is the simple “initiate request once access token is retrieved” pattern.

There are other patterns you could pursue, too. E.g., you could create a queue for authorized requests which is suspended until `RefreshTokenApi` resumes that queue. Then, all requests that require the token would be added that queue. Or you could use custom `Operation` pattern, where the `isReady` is set when the token is successfully retrieved. There are lots of ways to skin the cat, but hopefully this illustrates the idea, that we employ asynchronous patterns rather than ever “stopping” or “waiting”.

---

If you want to make sure that you allow concurrent requests to call `refreshTokenAPI`, then you can have it wait, but only do this on some background queue, and avoid ever blocking the caller thread:

```
private var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.domain.app.token") // custom serial queue to avoid blocking calling thread

func headers(methodType: String, methodName: String, request: URLRequest, isAddUserAuthorization: Bool, completion: @escaping (URLRequest) -> Void) {
    queue.async { [self] in
        var request = request

        // presumably you have code that is using methodType and methodName, too ...

        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        if isTokenExpired() {
            let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

            refreshTokenAPI { token in
                request.addValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "AccessToken")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(request) }
                semaphore.signal()
            }
            semaphore.wait()
        } else {
            request.addValue(getAccessTokenFromDefaults(), forHTTPHeaderField: "AccessToken")
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion(request) }
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, I might consider wrapping these network requests in a custom asynchronous subclass of `Operation` (or use Combine), but that is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I got the approach that you said, but how to handle if the POST method is called by multiple threads at the same time, it checks if the refresh token is expired and it calls Refresh token API multiple times right? How if the POST method is called at the same time? @Rob